# Getting an ID of checked RadioButton in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, onclicklistener, radio-group

I have a RadioGroup with 3 RadioButtons and a Button in my XML file. How can I get the ID of the checked RadioButton when I hit the Button (I have an OnClickListener set for this button)? Later I want to use Switch statement inside onClick, after checking which RadioButton is checked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
yourRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [getCheckedRadioButtonId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29) on your RadioGroup